# C Tcl commands not being recognized

Tags: c, tcl, codeblocks

Using codeblocks, I am attempting to run the following example I found online:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tcl.h>

main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Tcl_Interp *myinterp;
    char *action = "set a [expr 5 * 8]; puts $a";
    int status;

    printf("Your Program will run ... \n");

    myinterp = Tcl_CreateInterp();
    status = Tcl_Eval(myinterp, action);

    printf("Your program has completed\n");
}
```

However, running this yields the error:

```
C:/Users/amlut/Downloads/C/run/main.c:11: undefined reference to `_imp__Tcl_CreateInterp'
C:/Users/amlut/Downloads/C/run/main.c:12: undefined reference to `_imp__Tcl_Eval'
```

The intellisense in Codeblocks picks up the function when typing it out, so it seems that I linked the libraries and added the includes properly. Still, it throws an error when trying to run.

If any additional information is required, I would be happy to provide.

Thank you.

Comment: you need to add the libraries to the linker

Comment: I believe I did this. Project -> Build Options -> Linker Settings -> Add; then as well for search directories. The two .libs are `tclstub86_64` and `tkstub86`

Comment: your lib file should be .a and not .lib file;
run this in your lib folder findstr /s /m "_imp__Tcl_CreateInterp" *.a;
this will tell you what file you need to add to the linker

Comment: The libraries I have downloaded are all .lib. Is this causing the issue?

Comment: yes probably, try to download the  mingw version and not visual studio (.lib are for VS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are building an application that uses Tcl (and not an extension for Tcl) then you need to link against libtcl.so (or tcl.dll, or whatever the library is called on your OS), and *not* the stub library!

Also, you should call `Tcl_FindExecutable` (once!) before calling `Tcl_CreateInterp` so that the Tcl library itself can be initialised (e.g., it sets up how Tcl understands filenames). It takes one argument, which is usually either `argv[0]` or `NULL`; since you have `argv`, use `argv[0]`.

```
...

Tcl_FindExecutable(argv[0]);

myinterp = Tcl_CreateInterp();

...
```